# css IE and firefox problem

Tags: css, css-sprites

I have a button which I want at a certain poistion on the screen. Problem is in firefox its a little up and in IE its a little down. What can I do?

```
.btn1{
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 4%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 740px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are seeing differences between browsers is because you are using %.  % is calculated and rounded differently between different browsers.  Try using px or pt

Comment: Agreed: % is really not useful for vertical measurement. It's more of a horizontalthing.

Answer (score 0):

Do a normal stylesheet that makes it work on just Firefox. Then, do this:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="your-stylesheet-here.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Make this stylesheet a specific one for IE, so that the box looks correct on IE.

Comment: This is not a solution, just a dirty workaround. IE8+ is has pretty good support for CSS not to use CSS hacks.

Comment: There is very little justification to having separate stylesheets for IE.  With the right mark-up/CSS combination you can avoid having to use specific styles for IE.

Answer (score 0):

Put this at the top of the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you in your HTML code this?
   `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`
2. Use specified stylesheets:

   `<!--[if IE]>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="ie.css" />
   <![endif]-->`
3. Do you know that you can use: `margin: 4% 0px 0px 760px;`?
4. If you want to make something horizontally-center use: `margin: 0px auto;`. Cause 760px may crash in lower/higher resolutions.

Comment: "margin: 0px auto;" - this does not work in all browsers. IE6/7 require you to use text-align: center; on the wrapping element (or body) and no floats on the child you want centered so long as it has a fixed width.  Then reset text-align on the child to left so all your content isn't center aligned.

Comment: But with updates it is still better than specified margin ;) And i dodn't included IE6/7 text-align cause it is one-big crap.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by updates.  But using what you recommended is only going to fix his problem in some browsers, not all :P

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a "CSS reset"... Google for it :-)
Every Browser has his own default CSS, thats the problem ;-)